# how to call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile after CallShortcutExpressCheckout in paypal recurring profile express checkout

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have downloaded and implemented this paypal integration lib on my website.
https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Express-Checkout-example

The recurring profiles are not getting created.

The function call for Express checkout is

```
  $resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
  $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
  if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
  {
  // if SetExpressCheckout is returned with success, move to paypal site for payments.
  RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
  } 


function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL) 
    {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

        $nvpstr="&AMT=". $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=".urlencode("Test Recurring Payment($1 monthly)");
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;

        $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
        $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

        //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        //' Make the API call to PayPal
        //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
        if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
        {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
        }

        return $resArray;
    }
```

This function is for creating a recurring profile which is not called anywhere in the sample code.

```
function CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile()
    {
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------
        //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
        //' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
        //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
        //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
        //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
        //' the transaction
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------
        $token      = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
        $email      = urlencode($_SESSION['email']);
        $shipToName     = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToName']);
        $shipToStreet       = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToStreet']);
        $shipToCity     = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToCity']);
        $shipToState        = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToState']);
        $shipToZip      = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToZip']);
        $shipToCountry  = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToCountry']);

        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //' Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the
        //'  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $nvpstr="&TOKEN=".$token;
        #$nvpstr.="&EMAIL=".$email;
        $nvpstr.="&SHIPTONAME=".$shipToName;
        $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTREET=".$shipToStreet;
        $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCITY=".$shipToCity;
        $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTATE=".$shipToState;
        $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOZIP=".$shipToZip;
        $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=".$shipToCountry;
        $nvpstr.="&PROFILESTARTDATE=".urlencode("2011-07-01T0:0:0");
        $nvpstr.="&DESC=".urlencode("Test Recurring Payment($1 monthly)");
        $nvpstr.="&BILLINGPERIOD=Month";
        $nvpstr.="&BILLINGFREQUENCY=5";
        $nvpstr.="&AMT=1";
        $nvpstr.="&CURRENCYCODE=USD";
        $nvpstr.="&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
        //' If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
        //'     an action to complete the payment.  
        //' If failed, show the error
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray=hash_call("CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile",$nvpstr);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
        return $resArray;
    }
```

can I call this function to create the recurring profile in returnurl and pass the token id and payer id to this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of any library you're using, the flow should be [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) (optional), and then you can follow that up with either/or/both [DoExpresscheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) and [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/).

If you're going to use CRPP you need to make sure SEC includes the billing agreement parameters, otherwise you'll end up with an invalid token error when you call CRPP.  [Here's an old sample](http://www.angelleye.com/temp/sample-set.php) of RAW API requests flow to make it work.

Then, if you're interested, you may want to take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) to make this easier on you.  I know mine works.  :)

Comment: I am not getting when should I call CRPP function, I have set the billing parameters in SEC. In my checkout file I am calling SEC then redirect to paypal which lands me on success page. Between this flow when do I call CRPP fucntion. Should I call it again on success page?

Comment: After the user signs in to PayPal to review the order and clicks continue (or pay) they'll be sent back to your ReturnURL that you specify in the SEC request.  That is when you'll call GECD (if necessary) and CRPP to finalize the profile creation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew I already did in same way. I will be more satisfy if you have a look on my code once. I will upload the code file in some time and let you know. Thanks again for your paypal library. I also do refer the same to clear my doubts.

Comment: do I also need to call DoExpressCheckoutPayment? As of now I am calling SEC and then if response is success on my returnUrl I am calling CRPP function skipping the DECP.

Comment: That's fine, you don't need DECP if it doesn't fit your checkout model.  If you do need to process a general order payment separate from the profile setup, though, you could use both with the same token.